# how to check file type and opening/ saving files in a folder VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

The following code loops through All files in a specified folder, formats each file, and saves it as a PDF in the same folder.

The code runs fine but there are 2 issues:

1)if there are any files in the folder that are already pdf,s it will open in and mess it up. How can I make this so it only opens the excel files in the folder and not PDF files?

2)if I run it twice it works but it just saves over files if the filename already exists. How can I make I so if when it saves it and the file name already exists it saves it as a new file like filename-b, filename-c filename-d, filename-f ect?

```
Sub File_Loop_Example()
   
    Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       .Show
       MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
       Err.clear
    End With

    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\", vbReadOnly)

    Do While MyFile <> ""
        DoEvents
        On Error GoTo 0
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=False
        
        Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!TTDA"
        ChDir MyFolder
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
        
      0
        Workbooks(MyFile).Close SaveChanges:=False
        MyFile = Dir 
    Loop

    End Sub
```

Comment: "The following code loops through excel files in a specified folder" - not really, it loops through *all* files in a folder because you didn't specify an extension in the `Dir`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing of

```
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\", vbReadOnly)
```

with

```
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\" & "*.xlsx")
```

In this way, the code will open only `.xlsx` files.

Or you can let your code like it is, but filter the files to be open using the next function which retrieves the file extension:

```
Private Function GetExt(fileName As String) As String
   GetExt = Split(fileName, ".")(UBound(Split(fileName, ".")))
End Function
```

The function can be called just before the workbook opening. Your loop will become something like this:

```
Do While MyFile <> ""
     DoEvents
     If GetExt(MyFile) = "xlsx" or GetExt(MyFile) = "xlsm" then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=False
        
        Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!TTDA"
        ChDir MyFolder
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
        
        Workbooks(MyFile).Close SaveChanges:=False
     End if
     MyFile = Dir 
 Loop
```

For the next issue, use please:

```
Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fso.FileExists(MyFolder & "\" & MyFile & ".pdf") Then
       If fso.FileExists(MyFolder & "\" & MyFile & "_b.pdf") Then
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:= _
              MyFolder & "\" & MyFile & "_a", Quality:= _
              xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
       Else
          ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:= _
              MyFolder & "\" & MyFile & "_b", Quality:= _
              xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
        End If
    Else
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:= _
            MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, Quality:= _
            xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    End If
```

Comment: @atgold18:  Glad I could help!. But if the code answers your question, we here tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for something similar will know that the code works... Bye!